# Change Value in Bootstrap Pricing slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nice bootstrap pricing slider which originaly came from here: http://amirolahmad.github.io/bootstrap-pricing-slider/

The wierd thing is- the value change by the same number that display. For Example:

If i choose 100 at the first slider
and choose 1 on the second slider, i will get **100** at the total.

If i choose 2 on the second slider, i will get **200**. and so on.

I want to change the value at the code of the first slider, so when i choose 100 at the first slider and 1 on the second slider, it will give me **10** at the total- not 100.

Here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap Pricing Slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="price-box">

        <form class="form-horizontal form-pricing" role="form">

          <div class="price-slider">
            <h4 class="great">Amount</h4>
            <span>Minimum $10 is required</span>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div id="slider"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="price-slider">
            <h4 class="great">Duration</h4>
            <span>Minimum 1 day is required</span>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div id="slider2"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="price-form">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="amount" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Amount ($): </label>
              <span class="help-text">Please choose your amount</span>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="hidden" id="amount" class="form-control">
                <p class="price lead" id="amount-label"></p>
                <span class="price">.00</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="duration" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Duration: </label>
              <span class="help-text">Choose your commitment</span>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="hidden" id="duration" class="form-control">
                <p class="price lead" id="duration-label"></p>
                <span class="price">days</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="style">
            <div class="form-group total">
              <label for="total" class="col-sm-6 control-label"><strong>Total: </strong></label>
              <span class="help-text">(Amount * Days)</span>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="hidden" id="total" class="form-control">
                <p class="price lead" id="total-label"></p>
                <span class="price">.00</span>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Proceed <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right" style="padding-right: 10px;"></span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <img src="images/payment.png" class="img-responsive payment" />
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>

        <p class="text-center" style="padding-top:10px;font-size:12px;color:#2c3e50;font-style:italic;">Created by <a href="https://twitter.com/AmirolAhmad" target="_blank">AmirolAhmad</a></p>

      </div>

    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#slider").slider({
              range: "min",
              animate: true,
              value:1,
              min: 10,
              max: 1000,
              step: 10,
              slide: function(event, ui) {
                update(1,ui.value); //changed
              }
          });

          $("#slider2").slider({
              range: "min",
              animate: true,
              value:1,
              min: 1,
              max: 365,
              step: 1,
              slide: function(event, ui) {
                update(2,ui.value); //changed
              }
          });

          //Added, set initial value.
          $("#amount").val(0);
          $("#duration").val(0);
          $("#amount-label").text(0);
          $("#duration-label").text(0);

          update();
      });

      //changed. now with parameter
      function update(slider,val) {
        //changed. Now, directly take value from ui.value. if not set (initial, will use current value.)
        var $amount = slider == 1?val:$("#amount").val();
        var $duration = slider == 2?val:$("#duration").val();

        /* commented
        $amount = $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );
        $duration = $( "#slider2" ).slider( "value" );
         */

         $total = "$" + ($amount * $duration);
         $( "#amount" ).val($amount);
         $( "#amount-label" ).text($amount);
         $( "#duration" ).val($duration);
         $( "#duration-label" ).text($duration);
         $( "#total" ).val($total);
         $( "#total-label" ).text($total);

         $('#slider a').html('<label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> '+$amount+' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></label>');
         $('#slider2 a').html('<label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> '+$duration+' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></label>');
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would choosing 100 and 1 give you 10?

Comment: I need it for service pricing

Comment: So are you asking us what the math is to get 10 from 100?

Comment: I want to implement that via the code. Not to give you math exam.

Comment: You mean like this: `$total = "$" + ($amount * ($duration * 0.1));` ? (assuming $duration is the second slider you speak of)

Comment: Exacty ted! It worked! Please put your comment as an answer so i will rate you

Answer (score 0):

Ted said: `$total = "$" + ($amount * ($duration * 0.1));` ? (assuming $duration is the second slider you speak of)
The perfect working answer is:
`$total = "$" + ($amount * $duration * 0.1);`